# Adding header files in header files

Tags: c++, header

```
#ifndef LISTTEST_H
#define LISTTEST_H
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class ListTest {
    public:
        vector<T>* encrypt(vector<T> *list, int* key);
        void setkeyLength(int keyLength);
        int getKeyLength();
    private:
        int keyLength;
};


#endif  /* LISTTEST_H */
```

> I have included vector and string header files in my own header file, but in "vector* encrypt(vector *list, int* key);" the compiler is giving error that vector is undefined
>   what am I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify the `vector` using `std::vector`, as it's part of the `std` namespace. You should also consider removing `<string>`, as you don't use it in the header.

Comment: This is not the complete header file and I would need string class in my header file.

Comment: @SharadSharma, Okay, I was just going off of your code. I guess you forgot to take it out for the sscce (and using one is great of you btw).

Answer (score 1):

They are contained in `std` namespace:

```
std::vector<T>* encrypt(std::vector<T> *list, int* key);
```

Comment: Hah, beat you by one second. Right answer, though. +1

Comment: @chris: not bad to be beaten. ;)